# Changing the background of a ChartJS on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I have the following simple code running fine on node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var Canvas = require('canvas');
var Chart = require('nchart');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var canvas = new Canvas(400, 200);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)", //transparent
            strokeColor: "#f15a42",
            pointColor: "#f15a42",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [5, 9, 8, 1]
        }
    ]
    };

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {});
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    canvas.pngStream().pipe(res);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

It produces the following PNG image:

[image: chart]

It has a transparent background.
I'm able to change the background of the whole canvas (I want it solid white) until I add the chart to it. It should be a ChartJS feature but I could not find anything.

I'd be able to do it if I had a HTML canvas, not sure how to proceed with node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extend Chart.js to do this, like so

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.2)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.chart.width, this.chart.height);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    }
});
```

and then

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/q7v5qzzg/

Comment: Thank you, this works but I'm not sure why: could you explain a little?

Comment: Sure. globalCompositeOperation is a canvas context property that determines how new shapes will be incorporated into the canvas bitmap. The default value (source-over) just paints the new shape over all the existing shapes. destination-over is the opposite of that i.e. it paints the new shape under all the existing shapes - which is what we do - we fill the canvas with our fill color under the existing chart. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation for more. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,0)"

pass this as one of the configuration values

Comment: from the documentation, that should be the color of grid lines:  //String - Colour of the grid lines
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",